# Intro to Docker for FreeBSD Jail User - How and should I start the container with systemd?

Tags: docker

We're currently migrating room server to the cloud for reliability, but our provider doesn't have the FreeBSD option. Although I'm prepared to pay and upload a custom system image for deployment, I nontheless want to learn how to start a application system instance using Docker.

in [FreeBSD Jail](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/jails-build.html), what I did was to extract an entire `base.txz` directory hierarchy as system content into `/usr/jail/app`, and `pkg -r /usr/jail/app install apache24 php perl`; then I configured `/etc/jail.conf` to start the `/etc/rc` script in the jail.

I followed the official FreeBSD Handbook, and this is generally what I've worked out so far.

But Docker is another world entirely.

To build a Docker image, there are two options: a) import from a tarball, b) use a Dockerfile. The latter of which lets you specify a "`CMD`", which is the default command to run, but

Q1. why isn't it available from a)?

Q2. where are information like "`CMD ENV`" stored? in the image? in the container?

Q3. How to start a GNU/Linux system in a container? Do I just run systemd and let it figure out the rest from configuration? Do I need to pass to it some special arguments or envvars?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should think of a Docker container as a packaging around a single running daemon.  The ideal Docker container runs one process and one process only.  Systemd in particular is so heavyweight and invasive that it's actively difficult to run inside a Docker container; if you *need* multiple processes in a container then a lighter-weight init system like supervisord can work for you, but that's usually an exception more than a standard packaging.

Docker has an official tutorial on [building and running custom images](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/) which is worth a read through; this is a pretty typical use case for Docker.  In particular, best practice is to write a Dockerfile that describes how to build an image and check it into source control.  Containers should avoid having persistent data if they can (storing everything in an external database is ideal); if you change an image, you need to delete and recreate any containers based on it.  If local data is unavoidable then [either Docker volumes or bind mounts](https://docs.docker.com/storage/) will let you keep data "outside" the container.

While Docker has several other ways to create containers and images, none of them are as reproducible.  You should avoid the `import`, `export`, and `commit` commands; and you should only use `save` and `load` if you can't use or set up a Docker registry and are forced to move images between systems via a tar file.

On your specific questions:

Q1. I suspect the best reason the non-`docker build` paths to create images don't easily let you specify things like `CMD` is just an implementation detail: if you look at the `docker history` of an image you'll see the `CMD` winds up being its own layer.  Don't worry about it and use a Dockerfile.

Q2. The default `CMD`, any set `ENV` variables, and other related metadata are stored in the image alongside the filesystem tree.  (Once you launch a container, it has a normal Unix process tree, with the initial process being pid 1.)

Q3. You don't "start a system in a container".  Generally run one process or service in a container, and manage their lifecycles independently.